# Sprite Kit Moving Nodes using SKAction causing trouble

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit, skaction, sknode

I am trying to create a block game where I have a row of blocks, I slide the end block from right to left and each of the other blocks moves right 1 position. If I then slide the block back again they all slide left by 1 position.  The trouble I am having is that If i drag slowly it works fine but if I drag quickly back and forth the blocks get all messed up, they move over the top of each other so instead of a row of 6 I have a row of 4 as 2 blocks are sitting behind the other ones. Any advice is appreciated.

Here is code from my Scene.M

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

self.selectedNode = [self nodeAtPoint:[[touches anyObject] locationInNode:self]];

[self.selectedNode.physicsBody setDynamic:YES];
self.selectedNode.zPosition = 1;
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
CGPoint currentPoint = CGPointMake([[touches anyObject] locationInNode:self].x , selectedNode.position.y);
CGPoint previousPoint = CGPointMake([[touches anyObject] previousLocationInNode:self].x , selectedNode.position.y);
_deltaPoint = CGPointSubtract(currentPoint, previousPoint);
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {

CGPoint newPoint = CGPointAdd(self.selectedNode.position, _deltaPoint);

self.selectedNode.position = newPoint;

_deltaPoint = CGPointZero;

}

-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact{

SKNode *node = contact.bodyA.node;
if ([node isKindOfClass:[Block class]] && node != selectedNode) {
    [(Block *)node collidedWith:contact.bodyB contact:contact];
}

node = contact.bodyB.node;
if ([node isKindOfClass:[Block class]] && node != selectedNode) {
    [(Block *)node collidedWith:contact.bodyA contact:contact];
}
}
```

Here is my code from my Block.M

```
-(instancetype)initWithPosition:(CGPoint)pos andType:(NSString *)blockType{

SKTextureAtlas *atlas =
[SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed: @"Blocks"];
SKTexture *texture = [atlas textureNamed:blockType];
texture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;

if (self = [super initWithTexture:texture]){
    self.name = blockType;
    self.position = pos;
    self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(self.size.width - 30, self.size.height - 8)];
    self.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
    self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = 1;
    self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask =  0;
    self.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = 1;

}

return self;
}

- (void)collidedWith:(SKPhysicsBody *)body contact:(SKPhysicsContact*)contact {

CGPoint localContactPoint = [self.scene convertPoint:contact.contactPoint toNode:self];

if (localContactPoint.x < 0) {
    SKAction *moveLeftAction = [SKAction moveByX:-48 y:0 duration:0.0];
    [self runAction:moveLeftAction];
} else {
    SKAction *moveRightAction = [SKAction moveByX:48 y:0 duration:0.0];
    [self runAction:moveRightAction];
}
}
```

Comment: Use runAction:withKey: to ensure only one move action is running on a given node. Most likely your issue is because multiple move actions are stacked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have multiple move actions running simultaneously if you start a collision before previous move actions on a given block complete, which can lead to weird animations.

One fix is to remove existing animations before the next starts. Something like this (not tested):

```
- (void)collidedWith:(SKPhysicsBody *)body contact:(SKPhysicsContact*)contact {

CGPoint localContactPoint = [self.scene convertPoint:contact.contactPoint toNode:self];

    // If we have any move actions still in progress, complete them so we can start a new one
    if ([self actionForKey:@"blockMove"]) {
        [self removeActionForKey:@"blockMove"];
        self.position = CGPointMake(_targetX, self.position.y);
    }

    if (localContactPoint.x < 0) {
        _targetX = self.position.x - 48;
    } else {
        _targetX = self.position.x + 48;
    }
    SKAction *moveLeftAction = [SKAction moveToX:_targetX y:0 duration:0.0];
    [self runAction:moveLeftAction withKey:@"blockMove"];
}
```

Comment: Tried that but same issue . Some blocks are moving more than one block space. They all start lined up together then when sliding my finger back and forth quickly across the row only 2 or 3 are visible and the other spaces blank.

Comment: I also noticed that sometimes localContactPoint is positive when it should be negative so the block is moving right when it should be going left!

Comment: hmm... I wonder if it's a side-effect of using moveByX and calculating deltas instead of moveToX with destinations ... using deltas, if things get out of whack once they'll be off permanently. I've updated the explanation to use moveToX instead, does that work?

Comment: No moveToX has the same issue. Some blocks are still moving over top or under other blocks. Something to do with the speed of the physics?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know where to go from here, don't have enough experience debugging physics issues. Good luck!